# How to validate if a user exist in KeyCloak userModel

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to write a custom Authenticator. So in my `action()` method I am trying to look for existing user based on there userId.

```
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
.....
@Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        System.out.println("*******I AM INSIDE THE ACTION CONTROLLER***********");

        String userId = "8837fe42-0ec7-4117-aedb-75746078a101";

        //Code to look for user with userId then validate .
    }
```

I am new to keycloak, when I try to user the UserModel it says nullpointer exception

Regars

Answer (score 3):

You have to acquire `KeycloakSession` object first and then retrieve `UserProvider` as follows:

```
UserModel user = context.getSession().users().getUserById(userId, context.getRealm());
```

`KeycloakSession` is the starting point to access various application services.

Comment: Ok let me try, But I think I will get user doesn't exist in the session error. Ill reconfirm though